# Failed to complete tunnel connection error with ngrok

Tags: firewall, ngrok

```
Failed to complete tunnel connection
The connection to http://cc1e064782fc.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:80.

Make sure that a web service is running on localhost:80 and that it is a valid address.

The error encountered was: dial tcp [::1]:80: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Hi, I was setting up ngrok and got this error, I disabled the firewall too.

Take a look at this video where I show you the error.
https://youtu.be/uP4B79w4s7c

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of a message that ngrok successfully created tunnel to your pc at port 80 but there is no service running at that port in your OS, Mostly people run a web server at 80 but you can run any service at that port.

So lets assume you are running a web server in your OS on port 80 then you can access that web server from anywhere on the internet using that ngrok tunnel.